# Can i encrypt unmanaged disk in azure?

Tags: azure

I am attaching unmanaged data disks to vm using azure python module.I want to know is there a way to create encrypted unamanaged disk?

I am using the following code to create and attach datadisk to vm

```
def attach(clientid,clientsecret,tenantid,subscription_id):
        credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id = clientid,secret = clientsecret,tenant = tenantid)
        compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
        vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(
                'AzureARM-SanRamon-New-ResGrp',
                'az-win229'
            )
        disk=[{
                'name': 'mydatadisk6',
                    'disk_size_gb': 1,
                    'lun': 6,
                    'vhd': {
                        'uri' : "http://{}.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/mydatadisk6.vhd".format(
                            'crimasterdisks791')
                    },
                    'create_option': 'empty'


            },{
                'name': 'mydatadisk7',
                    'disk_size_gb': 1,
                    'lun': 7,
                    'vhd': {
                        'uri' : "http://{}.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/mydatadisk7.vhd".format(
                            'crimasterdisks791')
                    },
                    'create_option': 'empty'


            }]
        for each_disk in disk:
                vm.storage_profile.data_disks.append(each_disk)
        async_update = compute_client.virtual_machines.create_or_update(
                'AzureARM-SanRamon-New-ResGrp',
                'az-win229',
                vm,
            )
        async_update.wait()
```

But this is creating a unencrypted pageblob vhd and attaching to vm.I want to provide some option here to encrypt the blob vhd which will be created.Is that possible for now??

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Encrypt *how*? Blob storage is encrypted by default. If you're talking about app-level or os-level encryption, you'll need to do that yourself.

Comment: we can create encrypted managed disk using keyvaults similarly is there any way to create encrypted unmanaged disk

Comment: @NarinderVerma Yes, it is possible. You could encrypt an unmanaged VM, you could use Power Shell to do this, see this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/encrypt-disks

Comment: is there anything i can do within the above mentioned code i am using this to create and attach disk n i want to encrypt the disk within the same code as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the disk, attach it to vm and encrypt with OS features (bitlocker\dm-crypt). You can use [Azure VM Encryption extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption) as well.